# User with permission can't add an event to calendar by clicking

Tags: datetime

I have a working calendar (from the module calendar).

As administrator, i can click on a date and a popup allows me to add an event.

But users, who are allowed to add an event, can't do it. They can add an event by navigation and clicking on"add content", but they can't do it, like me, the administrator.

Can someone help me? I guess, it's somewhere in configuration but I don't find anything.

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify? You said:

> users, who are allowed to add an event, can't do it. They can add an
>   event by navigation and clicking on"add content", but they can't do it

- what do you mean they can't do it? Can they navigate to /node/add/[event] (I'm not sure what your event node type is called)? Or when they do go to /node/add/[event] does something happen when they try to save the new event?

Are you sure you have the permissions set correctly for their role? Check out the permissions at admin/people/permissions. Double check the permissions under Node.

Comment: Thank you for your time! They can't add an event by clicking straight on the event calendar. They don't get a popup. As administrator, i can click on the calendar and I get a popup. (It gets my costumer frustrated). But I'll try your advice, thanks!